# Quiero crear DOM mediante este array (metodo for each) y no puedo

Tags: javascript

He creado este ARRAY que contiene 4 objetos, cada objeto representa un PERIFERICO DE PC, ahora.. a cada Objeto le asigne un array que posee diferentes objetos que serian la cantidad de productos diferentes que hay de cada periferico. Quisiera crear un iterador forEach para mostrar por DOM solo lo nombres de los objetos (HEADSET, MOUSE, KEYBOARD Y NOTEBOOK) pero no sabria bien como acceder unicamente a ese nombre. Se que seria mas facil simplemente crear un array con esos 4 nombres e iterarlos, pero queria saber si se puede aprovechar el que ya cree para no repetir codigo !

```
`const listProducts = [
        {
            "KEYBOARD": [
                {
                    id: 0,
                    category: "Keyboard",
                    brand: "Razer",
                    name: "Huntsman V2 Analog US",
                    price: 200,
                    imgPath: "../images/products/Keyboard_0.webp"
                },
                {
                    id: 1,
                    category: "Keyboard",
                    brand: "Razer",
                    name: "Huntsman V2 Tenkeyless Linear Optical Switch",
                    price: 250,
                    imgPath: "../images/products/Keyboard_1.webp"
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    category: "Keyboard",
                    brand: "Razer",
                    name: "Huntsman Mini Linear Optical Switch",
                    price: 170,
                    imgPath: "../images/products/Keyboard_2.webp"
                },
                {
                    id: 3,
                    category: "Keyboard",
                    brand: "Razer",
                    name: "Pro Type Ultra US",
                    price: 200,
                    imgPath: "../images/products/Keyboard_3.webp"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            HEADSET: [
                {
                    id: 0,
                    category: "Headset",
                    brand: "Razer",
                    name: "BlackShark V2 Pro Black",
                    price: 200,
                    imgPath: "../images/products/Headset_0.webp"
                },
                {
                    id: 1,
                    category: "Headset",
                    brand: "Razer",
                    name: "BlackShark V2 Six Siege Edition",
                    price: 250,
                    imgPath: "../images/products/Headset_1.webp"
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    category: "Headset",
                    brand: "Razer",
                    name: "BlackShark V2 White Edition",
                    price: 170,
                    imgPath: "../images/products/Headset_2.webp"
                },
                {
                    id: 3,
                    category: "Headset",
                    brand: "Razer",
                    name: "Pro Type Ultra US",
                    price: 200,
                    imgPath: "../images/products/Headset_3.webp"
                }

            ]
        },
        {
            MOUSE: [
                {
                    id: 0,
                    category: "Mouse",
                    brand: "Razer",
                    name: "Viper Ultimate Quartz",
                    price: 200,
                    imgPath: "../images/products/Mouse_0.webp"
                },
                {
                    id: 1,
                    category: "Mouse",
                    brand: "Razer",
                    name: "Viper Ultimate Mercury",
                    price: 250,
                    imgPath: "../images/products/Mouse_1.webp"
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    category: "Mouse",
                    brand: "Razer",
                    name: "Viper Ultimate Black",
                    price: 170,
                    imgPath: "../images/products/Mouse_2.webp"
                },
                {
                    id: 3,
                    category: "Mouse",
                    brand: "Razer",
                    name: "Viper 8KHz ESL Edition",
                    price: 200,
                    imgPath: "../images/products/Mouse_3.webp"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            NOTEBOOK: [
                {
                    id: 0,
                    category: "Notebook",
                    brand: "Razer",
                    name: "Blade 14-QHD 165Hz GeForce RTX 3080Ti",
                    price: 200,
                    imgPath: "../images/products/Notebook_0.webp"
                },
                {
                    id: 1,
                    category: "Notebook",
                    brand: "Razer",
                    name: "Razer Blade 15 - UHD 144Hz GeForce RTX 3080Ti",
                    price: 250,
                    imgPath: "../images/products/Notebook_1.webp"
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    category: "Notebook",
                    brand: "Razer",
                    name: "Razer Blade 17 . QHD 240Hz GeForce RTX 3070 Ti",
                    price: 170,
                    imgPath: "../images/products/Notebook_2.webp"
                },
                {
                    id: 3,
                    category: "Notebook",
                    brand: "Razer",
                    name: "Book - UHD Touch 60Hz - Intel® Iris® Xe",
                    price: 200,
                    imgPath: "../images/products/Notebook_3.webp"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
let categoryFragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    listProducts.forEach(category => {
        let liCategory = document.createElement("li");
        liCategory.textContent = "DONT KNOW WHAT TO DO HERE"

    })`
```

Comment: Buen día, has publicado tu pregunta en el sitio de Stack Overflow en español, la pregunta está en un idioma que no es el oficial en este sitio y por lo tanto puede ser cerrada o votada negativamente. Te recomiendo que leas la sección [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Puedes traducir tu pregunta o publicarla en el sitio de Stack Overflow en inglés.

Comment: Ya cambio el idioma. Disculpa !

Comment: el titulo tambien!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estuve provando tu objeto y me costo bastante saber como funciona xDDD hasta que logre hacerlo funcionar, para llamarlo tienes que hacer :

```
listProducts[0].KEYBOARD[0].id
```

lo cual literalmente te dara mucho problemas a futuros ya que para hacerlo funcionar necetarias una iteracion tras otra (for tras for tras for tras for), te recomendarias algo mas como:

```
    const listProducts = [
        {
            id: 0,
            category: "Keyboard",
            brand: "Razer",
            name: "Huntsman V2 Analog US",
            price: 200,
            imgPath: "../images/products/Keyboard_0.webp"
        },
        {
            id: 0,
            category: "Headset",
            brand: "Razer",
            name: "BlackShark V2 Pro Black",
            price: 200,
            imgPath: "../images/products/Headset_0.webp"
        }
    ]
```

ya que de por si ya estas repitiendo la catergoria en el titulo y con esta metodologia ya solo tendrias que

```
productos = listProducts;
productos.forEach(element => {
  console.log(element.id);
  console.log(element.category);
});
```

lo digo porque para mostrar el nombre de las keys es tan facil como

```
for(var key in listProducts){
  console.log(key);
}
```

pero al tener todo con array (como lo expuse al principio) ese ciclo for solo te mostrara 0, 1, 2, 3

Comment: Hola ! Si, asi lo tenia antes, queria ver si se podia desarmar ! Bueno, muchas gracias !!!!

Comment: Igual te recomendaría publicarlo en foro en ingles quizás puedas tener otra respuesta.